# Check which SSH key was used to login

Tags: 12.04, ssh, authentication, log

So stupidly enough in our development team every individual SSH Key is used to access the root user directly.

When Checking the auth.log I can find this

```
Dec 18 09:45:04 webserver sshd[12377]: Accepted publickey for root from xx.xx.xx.xx port xx ssh2
Dec 18 09:45:04 webserver sshd[12377]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Is there any way to see which publickey was used? Maybe change something for the log levels? Or do I need to look in another place?

Comment: Happy with the below answer?

Comment: @Adel very much thank you. Sorry for the late acceptence currently in hospital. Our daughter was born 4 days ago

Comment: What a wonderful news! Congratulations!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, this is possible to do.

Change your ssh log level to VERBOSE and restart ssh. Usually the file is located:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find LogLevel option and change it to VERBOSE.

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

Restart SSH service

```
sudo service ssh restart; sudo service sshd restart;
```

Reconnect to ssh and check the log file.

```
nano /var/log/auth.log
```

Then you'll find something like this:

```
Dec 23 22:43:42 localhost sshd[29779]: Found matching RSA key: d8:d5:f3:5a:7e:27:42:91:e6:a5:e6:9e:f9:fd:d3:ce

Dec 23 22:43:42 localhost sshd[29779]: Accepted publickey for caleb from 127.0.0.1 port 59630 ssh2
```

Finally, relax and you're welcome :)